# How to create and access dynamic variable names a template function?

Tags: python, function, templates, variables, dynamic

I wound up having three extremely similar functions in my code, which were to take separate user inputs for their birth year, month, and day. I want to use the best practices I can even though the code is extremely basic, which is why it's a bit overkill. So right now I have a function that acts as a template and takes three args dateType, typeStr, and typeFormat. I'm trying to use these args to name variables in the three functions that I'll create using the template so that I can later print out the birth date of the person. I'm aware of scope, but I've tried making things global etc etc and it hasn't worked. I don't know if I'm even creating variables that are persistent or if it all gets unassigned once the function is done, and if I am creating variables I can't figure out what they're called as I've tried every possibility.

```
def makeTemplateInput(dateType, typeStr, typeFormat):
    def templateInput(dateType, typeStr, typeFormat):
        print('You\'re using the template function. Please input your birth {} in the format {}.\n$ '.format(dateType, typeFormat), end='')
        while True:
            try:
                dateType = input()
                typeStr = dateType
                dateType = int(dateType)

                if dateType > 0:
                    if len(typeStr) != len(typeFormat) and isinstance(dateType, int):
                        print('Your input doesn\'t have {} digits, please use the format {}.\n$ '.format(str(len(typeFormat)), typeFormat), end='')
                        print('strlen: ' + str(len(typeStr)))
                        continue
                    break
                else:
                    print('Your input is not a positive integer!\n$ ', end='')
                    continue

            except ValueError:
                print('Your input is not a valid number, please use the format {} where {} is an integer.\n$ '.format(typeFormat, str(typeFormat[:1])), end='')

        print(dateType)



def yearInput1():
    makeTemplateInput('year', 'yearStr', 'YYYY')

yearInput1()
```

`print('Your birthdate is: {}/{}/{}'.format(yearInput1.year, monthInput.monthStr, dayInput.dayStr))`

I'm sure it's a mess that misunderstands fundamental things about Python, but I really don't understand what's gone wrong.

Comment: `makeTemplateInput` just creates a function and doesn't do anything with it. It doesn't seem necessary, you could just remove it. " I'm trying to use these args to name variables in the three functions that I'll create using the template so that I can later print out the birth date of the person." You can't do that, but why would you need to?

Comment: Noted, I'll remove makeTemplateInput. In the final snippet of code I posted you can see sort of what I want to do, but I can't figure out how to take those variables from functions that I've created using the template. I want to be able to name the variables in the functions using args for the template or something like that so that I don't have to copy/paste three functions.

Comment: Stop thinkin in terms of variables. *Objects* that you need outside your function *should be returned in some form*.

Comment: "I want to be able to name the variables in the functions using args for the template or something like that so that I don't have to copy/paste three functions." Why do you need different variable names?

Comment: I suppose I don't need different variable names, so then my question is how do I take a variable from my newly made yearInput1() and use it to print the birthdate? doing year1Input.anyvariablename tells me that it has no anyvariablename member. As for your comment about objects, I don't understand that - I'm not there yet unfortunately

Comment: Yes, you are. *Everything* is an object. An object is just whatever the variable refers to. Again, you need to use `return` (or global variables, **but you shouldn't use global variables**).

Answer (score 0):

A few online classes or some good books can help with some of this confusion. I've created some sample code to hopefully answer your question. Thank you.

```
class Calendar:
    def __init__(self, day, month, year): #This can be initialised with the day/month/year
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year

    def displayDate(self): #This will display the dates from the object created/set
        print('day:{} month:{} year:{}'.format(self.day, self.month, self.year))

    def setNewDate(self, otherDay, otherMonth, otherYear): #this sets the class attributes to something else
        print('This was the old values day:{} month:{} year:{}'.format(self.day, self.month, self.year))
        self.day = otherDay
        self.month = otherMonth
        self.year = otherYear
        print('The new values are day:{} month:{} year:{}'.format(self.day, self.month, self.year))

cal = Calendar(6,11,2020)
cal.displayDate()
cal.setNewDate(3,4,2099)
```